# Exception with crystal reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am developing application which uses SAP Crystal Reports for reporting with Visual Studio 2013 Professional. 
I downloaded and install package from SAP site, install that. Report is prepared using wizard (this works correctly). Problem is if I following step in source code:

```
myCrystalReport.SetDataSource(myDataSet);
```

myDataSet is filled with required data. Displayed error is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports
>   for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP  BusinessObjects Enterprise XI
>   4.0\win32_x86\dotnet1\crdb_adoplus.dll' or one of its  dependencies.

During installation folder dotnet1 were not created. There is only folder dotnet.
Do somebody know how can be this problem resolved?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try uninstalling crystal reports and install it again in a different path.

Comment: Kushan I tried that. Moreover during installation there is no dialog, where I can choose installation directory. But i tried uninnstal it, and then install again. Result is the same - error above.

Comment: Can you try by changing the .NET framework version? 4.5 is my preference. Please take a backup before doing that. Because some times it may screw-up the solution.

Comment: Kushan Thanks, but this solution and all projects in this solution are based on .NET 4.5.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crystal reports error in SetDataSource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940940/crystal-reports-error-in-setdatasource)

Answer (score 32):

I had the exact same problem.  My solution was to add this xml to the app.config file inside the `<configuration>` level:

```xml
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
   <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

**See also**:

- [CRVS2010- crdb_adoplus.dll not found](https://refat38.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/crvs2010-crdb_adoplus-dll-not-found/)
- [Could not load file or assembly crdb_adoplus.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601741/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-crdb-adoplus-dll)

Comment: Could you explain how you found out the solution and why this error happens?

Comment: I don't know why this error happens but I found the solution by Googling it.  The sources I used from that were both listed on my original answer in the 'See also' bit.

Answer (score 5):

```
<configuration>
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
</startup>
</configuration>
```

Due to mixed mode assemblies has changed this problem will occur so it is recommended to you use above code into app.config file.

Answer (score 3):

you have use below code in app.config and also have to set .net profile 4 client to .net profile 4 or 4.5 in project property.

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

Comment: this is well covered by the existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

All above solution not working in my project and application goes in break mode. i solve this problem by adding following lines in app.config inside the configuration.

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
</startup>
```